# Account activation by non-admin user

Tags: accounts

When it comes to Account activation type (cp/settings/members) I have opted for “Manually moderated by administrator ” Is there any way to grant this right to non-admin user?

I don’t see the possibility to list this right in Member Group policy. Any hook or add-ons that do the work?

Thanks Enrico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, member groups can be allowed to edit other members and other member groups.

Edit the member group you wish to allow access to member authority; the CP URL looks like this:

```
/cp/members/groups/edit/{member_group_id}
```

In the settings for this member group, you can allow access to the members area and authority to modify member and member groups. See the attached image. If you allow a member group to `Edit members`, they should be able to activate/deactivate/whatever you need.

[image]